# How to deploy to Azure Storage in WebApps for Containers using own containers images

Tags: azure, web-applications, containers

I am using WebApps for Containers with my own container image. In WebApps you can mount the /home directory from Azure Storage for persistence data.

I would like to deploy my code to the Azure Storage via git but when Im using my own container images, the "Deployment Option" tab appear disabled and there is not git publish repository to do it.

How I can use the /home directory with persistent data?

PS. Deploying PHP applications.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your git remote like this:

```
git remote add azure https://{appname}.scm.azurewebsites.net
```

Now `git push azure master` will deploy to `/home/site/wwwroot`.

App Service storage will automagically get mounted inside your container as `/home`. Naturally, you still need to make sure whatever runs inside your container looks for code in the right path - e.g. for `nginx`:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    localhost;

    location / {
        root    /home/site/wwwroot;
    }
}
```

Comment: It was interesting , but using the https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/php/blob/master/7.0.6-apache/Dockerfile to create my own image, I can see enabled now the deployment option tab.

I think maybe is also because now I have ssh connection to the container (in my other images, I didn't configure that).

Comment: No idea what enables/disabled that blade. You should open an issue in that repo you just mentioned. Your question is valid.